# Trying to send a string to php file using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

So i am trying to send a string into a php file using ajax but the http.send is not working, maybe something is wrong with the code? (i am just a beginner)

```
 mainlink= 'a link';
 id= 'an id';
 $(document).click(function(){
   var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var link = mainlink+id;
   http.open("POST", 'test.php', true);
   http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   http.onload = function(){
     if(this.status == 200) {
       console.log (link);
     }
   }
   http.send("link="+link);
 });
```

test.php:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['link'])){
echo $_POST['link'];
} else{echo "error";}
?>
```

i tried both GET and POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. Are you sourcing in jQuery? Paste this tag inside the head tag of your page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It also seems probable that you want to console log `this.responseText` instead of `link` so you actually log what the server is responding rather than what you sent. Here is the exact code I used to get this working:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
                var mainlink = 'a link';
                var id = 'an id';
                $(document).click(function(){
                    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    var link = mainlink + id;
                    http.open("POST", 'test.php', true);
                    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    http.onload = function(){
                        if (this.status == 200){
                            console.log(this.responseText);
                        }
                    }
                    http.send("link=" + link);
                });
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['link'])){
        echo $_POST['link'];
    }
    else{
        echo "error";
    }
?>
```

You can see it working live [here](http://mintymark.com/test/). Is your pathname correct for `test.php`?

Comment: still nothing :(

Comment: The fact the console.log(this.responseText) displays the link is evidence that test.php received the link properly and sent back to you exactly what it received.

Comment: well thats strange, **console.log(this.responseText);** displays the link correctly but the file wont echo the link

Comment: so then why wont it echo in the file itself? yes they're in the same directory

Comment: Like when you visit a direct link to the PHP file, you expect it to show the link in the browser?

Comment: yes! exactly is that not what echo $_POST['link'] does?

Comment: OH NOW I GET IT!
thankyou so much! :) if see it from the filesystem console it works!

Comment: Awesome! if this is the answer you were looking for, please mark the answer with an upvote and accepted checkmark to let others know you're satisfied with it. It'll give me some points as well. Thanks!